# Task Status in SharePoint 2007 not changing when it is changed in Outlook

Tags: 2007, outlook, update

I can create a task in Outlook and assign it to myself. I have synchronized Outlook with SharePoint so the Task appears in my Outlook Task Pane. All good so far.

When I mark the task as complete and add an update, the update appears on SharePoint but the status has not been updated to complete but still shown as open.

Any idea as to why the status is not being updated whilst the comment is?

Answer (score 0):

To debug the issue I would use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to see the requests sent to and the response received from SharePoint.

You should see a request invoking the UpdateListItems web service, as described in [this post](https://pholpar.wordpress.com/2011/12/30/synchronizing-sharepoint-tasks-with-outlook-including-categories/).